# How to comment out code between two comments in C++

Tags: vim

IF I have several code sections that looks like:

```cpp
// XXX DEBUG
printf("example code");
int y = 6;
// XXX END DEBUG
```

I'd like to, in vim, run a command to comment out the bits between `XXX DEBUG` and `XXX END DEBUG`:

```cpp
// XXX DEBUG
// printf("example code");
// int y = 6;
// XXX END DEBUG
```

I've tried using `:g` with the delimiter switched

```
:g#^.*// XXX DEBUG#.,#^.*// XXX END DEBUG#normal I//
```

But that just lands me the error message `E492: Not an editor command: .,#^.*// XXX END DEBUG#normal I//`

Comment: This is not a C++ question, hence using the tag [tag:c++] is illegal.

Comment: type `//` manually or use your ide to do it for you and for that you will just have to consult its documentation.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, my 'ide' is vim, the documentation doesn't cite my issue, hence my posting

Comment: https://www.meetgor.com/vim-un-comment-p1/, https://linuxhint.com/comment-multiple-lines-vim/ (just one google search away)

Comment: I mark the first line I want to comment (e.g. `ma`), move to the last line (address will be `.`), and replce the line start `^` with `//`, which have to be escaped: `'a,.s/^/\/\//` There are probably better ways to do it, but that's in my muscle memory.

Comment: Isn't it funny when IDE folks try to teach Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alternative separator in a range. One good reason is that it is hard to know if you mean `/foo/` or `?foo?` when you do `<whatever>foo<whatever>`. Using an alternative separator in `:help :g` or `:help :s` is possible because such a confusion is not possible in that context.

Therefore, you can keep your `#`s for the "`:global`" part but you need to either escape your `//` in the range for `:normal`:

```
:g#^.*// XXX DEBUG#.,/^.*\/\/ XXX END DEBUG/normal I// <-- space here
```

or us `\v` to alter the "magicness" of the pattern:

```
:g#^.*// XXX DEBUG#.,/\v^.*// XXX END DEBUG/normal I// <-- space here
```

Now, that works:

```
// // XXX DEBUG
// printf("example code");
// int y = 6;
// // XXX END DEBUG
```

Hmm… kind of.

As-is, you are prepending `//`  to the lines *between* the matching lines but also to the matching lines themselves because of missing offsets:

```
             here -+             and here -+
                   |                       |
                   V                       V
:g#^.*// XXX DEBUG#.,/\v^.*// XXX END DEBUG/normal I// <-- space here
```

In the fixed version below,

- the range for `:normal` must start on the line *below* the matching line, so you would use `.+` or simply `+`,
- and it must end on the line *above* the search match, so you would use `/re/-`.

This is how it should look:

```
:g#^.*// XXX DEBUG#.+,/\v^.*// XXX END DEBUG/-normal I// <-- space here
```